# How to get the change logs of updated packages via pip / pipenv CLI?

Tags: python, pip, pipenv, changelog

I wonder if it's possible to grab the change logs of updated packages after running

`pip install [package_name] --upgrade`

or

`pipenv update`

Most of packages will have change logs in their repo. e.g

- https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests-html/releases
- https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/master/CHANGELOG.rst
- https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/blob/master/CHANGES.rst

It will be more productive if I could have the latest updates via CLI.

Comment: AFAIK change logs are not defined in "Metadata for Python Software Packages" PEPs: [241](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0241), [314](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0314), [345](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0345), [566](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0566). Ergo: such functionality could not be guaranteed to work. To create a script that **could** collect change logs for **some** packages - obviously must be possible. I am not aware of such attempts, do somebody?

Answer (score 0):

As a work around, I have been using the [Changelogs module](https://github.com/pyupio/changelogs) it uses heuristics to attempt to get a changelog, but of course due to plenty of packages doing their own thing, it will never be able to work for all packages.

I did test it on your 3 sample packages, `requests`, `pytest`, `urllib3` and was successful for printing out a changelog for them.